# I2C ADV7511 communication

Tags: fpga, c, i2c, arm, xilinx

I am currently trying to communicate via I2C to HDMI transmitter ADV7511 from Zynq 7000 Soc, I used  [this example](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/iicps/examples/xiicps_polled_master_example.c) as a reference for start, but yet without success, program get stuck in function `XIicPs_MasterSendPolled()` at this lines of code

```
    /*
     * Check for completion of transfer.
     */
    while ((IntrStatusReg & XIICPS_IXR_COMP_MASK) != XIICPS_IXR_COMP_MASK){

        IntrStatusReg = XIicPs_ReadReg(BaseAddr, XIICPS_ISR_OFFSET);
        /*
         * If there is an error, tell the caller.
         */
        if ((IntrStatusReg & Intrs) != 0U) {
            return (s32)XST_FAILURE;
        }
    }
```

It never exits from this `while` loop, what are possible reasons, or advices what to check?

Thanks!

Comment: don't know if that's the case here, but the Zynq's I²C hardware (a Cadence IP) has a *serious* bug that makes multiple consecutive address impossible. You might want to look into Moritz Fischer's I²C Uboot work, I think it contains a software workaround.

Comment: @MarcusMüller how I can confirm that I have a problem with Cadence IP?

Comment: not deep enough in that material. As said, look at Moritz' Uboot I²C work, and what he wrote about that. I can't take that research effort away from you, sorry.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am not really sure, but this is very similar to what I get https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/61665.html

Comment: @Lazar - I have not used either of those 2 devices, so can't help with direct experience of them. However in any case of I2C issues, I would first check the bus with an oscilloscope (a) to check the analog measurements are correct (rise/fall times, high/low voltage levels etc.), and (b) to look at exactly what I2C bus behaviour *immediately precedes* the point where the code hangs, looking for anything abnormal or unusual. Good luck.

Comment: I used ILA (Integrated Logic Analyzer) to follow SCL and SDA signals from I2C0 peripheral, but nothing on both of them. In which case should I expect SCL clock pulses? Is it enabled immediately when I2C peripheral is configured? @SamGibson

Comment: @Lazar - (a) For this purpose, using the ILA is not as good as using an oscilloscope, as I suggested. That is because some I2C issues are only visible when looking at the analog waveform of the signals. (b) Please describe your physical I2C bus - e.g. what total length, which devices on it, what pull-up resistors and to what voltage etc.? (c) Have you successfully used that I2C bus on that specific SOC to communicate with any other I2C device, or is the ADV7511 your first attempt? (d) "nothing on both of them" What *exactly* do you mean by "nothing" - what logic level did the ILA display?

Comment: I had this problem also, but I do not remember how I fixed it. The code example provided is correct, and no problems with HDMI driver. It was something to do with properly performing repeated start during I2C read. Look at that more closely at I2C configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that could go wrong.  If this is at boot time, the ADV7511 may not yet be ready, it may need more boot time.

Or, its clock pumping it too fast.  Nothing like real probes to look at the signals.   Lacking that, then Cadence IP, may be able to show a model of the communication.

Or as simple as your default pull ups and pull downs on the ADV7511 not being set right, for your method of communication to it.

Or just for grins, way slow down the communication clock to the ADV.
My quick look at your code tells me you are using the system default clock.  That's probably in the 20MHz to 100MHz plus range..?  When a set up comm port on a chip like a ADV is expecting much slower comm.  I2C is in clock ranges like 100KHz.